# Modify the function to invoke the given callback and return its result

Tags: javascript

Guys this has me stumped! Anyhelp would be awesome!We haven't been taught this and its blowing my mind.

```
function invokeCallback(cb) {
alert (CB)
}

enter code here

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const exampleCallback = function() {
  return 'hello';
};

const invokedResult = invokeCallback(exampleCallback);

console.log(invokedResult, '<-- should be "hello"');
```

Comment: Why is that tagged with java?

Comment: How can I edit my post. Sorry!

Comment: Your code assumes that `alert()` is a synchronous call.

Comment: if you want to return the value, why are you `alert`ing it? Also you need to call cb using `()`. Just `return cb()` in your invokeCallback.

Comment: There literally is nothing special. A callback is a function, treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

To print output in console you don't need alert. Just return the function `cb()`

```
function invokeCallback(cb) {
    return cb();
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const exampleCallback = function() {
  return 'hello';
};

const invokedResult = invokeCallback(exampleCallback);

console.log(invokedResult);
```